# How do I debug my PIC16F15323 code?

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

Microchip PIC16F15323 topic
I have source code that compiles fine under Microchip's mpasmx
Somewhere in there I may have a bug as unlikely as that may seem.
I would like to debug my code.

I have MPLAB IDE and also MPLAB X IDE
MPLAB IDE doesn't let me say it is the P16F15323
MPLAB X IDE demands that I set the compiler before it will let me make a project but it doesn't have any place to do that.
Is there some way to tell one of these to stop its silly nonsense and work?
Is there an alternative that is simple to use?

Comment: MPLABX v5.40 doesn't have MPASM. To use MPASM you'd need to download MPLABX 
v5.35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am calling this the answer:

Thanks to the help so far, I have made great progress. I got the new version of the assembler to assemble my code. It was via a bit of "tom foolery" so I will document for others.

1. I installed the XC8 compiler and MPLABX-v5.40 (v5.5 didn't like my Java 1.8).
2. I started a new project and told it to make a new assembly source code file.
3. I then copy and pasted my code into that file.
4. Make then would attempt to assemble.

This doesn't mean success, but rather that the new issue is too different to remain under this heading.

Comment: Ken Smith - Thanks for summarizing this in an answer. Please consider [accepting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an answer, if you have finished with this topic. Please also consider "upvoting" all answers which helped you, even if you choose a different answer (or your own) as the answer to accept. See more in the link I gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your MPLAB-X installation is corrupt or very old. You should be able to select the assembler where it asks you to select a compiler.

[image]

As you can see, versions at least 4.01 and newer support the chip you have in mind, and 3.4 does not.

You may have to install the free version of [XC8](https://microchipdeveloper.com/xc8:installation) to get the assembler. I think at some point in the past they combined the two.

Comment: For MPLABX, use the [XC Series](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-xc-compilers) toolchains, which include MPASM.  For the old MPLAB, it likely does not support that chip.

Comment: I must have a corrupt version.  I don't see that list.

Comment: @KenSmith Make sure you have the [XC8 compiler](https://microchipdeveloper.com/xc8:installation)  installed.

Comment: Please remember, there are some differences between MPASM and the XC8 assembler, See: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM%20to%20MPLAB%20XC8%20PIC%20Assembler%20Migration%20Guide%2050002973A.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The MPLAB IDE is to old to support the PIC16F15323, so you had to switch to MPLABX IDE.
And here please remember:
The Assembler MPASM is included in the MPLABX toolchain only when the version is below 5.4. If you want to work with the newest version (MPLAX 5.45) you had to install the xc8 compiler and to work with the assembler supplied with the compiler. But please remember, there are several differences between the two assembler. You can't copy you òld`assembler code from an MPASM project into an pic-as project. See here for [details](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM%20to%20MPLAB%20XC8%20PIC%20Assembler%20Migration%20Guide%2050002973A.pdf).
So if you want to work with MPASM you had to install e.g. MPLABX 5.35., which is of course the easiest way.